# How to delete the records by using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table like below

```
first_name last_name email emplid
   a         b        c
   a         b        c      1
   d         e        f    
   d         e        f      2
   g         h        i
```

I  want to keep the record of `ab` and `de` that have `emplid` and record of `gh` too.

Thanks

Comment: Tried something? Share that...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28SQL%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29

Comment: `delete from table where emplid =''`... google update and delete commands..I assumed that you are using MySQL

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: why everybody assumed that it's null and not empty?

Comment: @cho360 - Not everybody. `Mark S` commented on this and got my upvote.

Comment: Since no information was given about the table structure and the column looks like it is numeric giving answers based on it being null is just as good as giving answers based on it being empty. The same thing can be asked about your comment suggesting an answer, why did you assume it was empty and not null?

Answer (score 2):

What does has emplid mean? Is this means not null, then this should do the trick:

```
delete from tablename where not emplid is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE emplid IS NULL OR emplid="";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE emplid IS NULL
```

This will get rid of rows with NULL emplid. If this is an empty string you can add:

```
OR emplid = ''
```

If this doesn't work, let us know what you have tried and what version of SQL you are using.

Based on your update where you also want to keep the row with gh, add
OR (first_name = 'g' and last_name = 'h')

Comment: down vote favorite
 

I have a table like below

first_name last_name email emplid
   a         b        c
   a         b        c      1
   d         e        f    
   d         e        f      2
   g         h        i

I want to keep the record of ab and de that have emplid and record of gh too.

Thanks

Comment: @haoyun That sounds like a different question. You might want to update your original question with those new specs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what your value for emplid is, but if it's NULL, then you can use something like:

```
delete from test where emplid is null;
```

if it's the empty string, then you can do something like:

```
delete from test where emplid = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Delete From [YourTableName] where emplid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM tablename WHERE emplid IS NULL OR emplid=''